# how to implement object reference as array fields in PHP

Tags: php

Is it possible in PHP and how it is implemented, if possible:

```
$obj = new Build();
$obj['name'] = 'Main;
'$obj['flat'] = 90;
$obj->save();
```

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php

Comment: you can extend your class from http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php but why? That is kind wrong direction. why do you need it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement [ArrayAccess Interface](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) at the object.

Or to wrap into a proxy implementing the ArrayAccess Interface and converting access by index into access to property or into calls to getters/setters.

I would also recommend to consider to use some mapping solution, like [JMS Serializeer](https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer). JMS can receive an array and map it to an object by defined rules.